# Replace escape sequence characters in a string in Python 3.x

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have used the following code to replace the escaped characters in a string. I have first done splitting by `\n` and the used `re.sub()`, but still I dont know what I am missing, the code is not working according to the expectations. I am a newbie at Python, so please don't judge if there are optimisation problems. Here is my **code**:

```
#import sys
import re

String = "1\r\r\t\r\n2\r\r\n3\r\r\r\r\n\r\n\r4\n\r"
splitString = String.split('\n')
replacedStrings = []
i=0

for oneString in splitString:
    #oneString = oneString.replace(r'^(.?)*(\\[^n])+(.?)*$', "")
    oneString = re.sub(r'^(.?)*(\\[^n])+(.?)*$', "", oneString)
    print(oneString)
    replacedStrings.insert(i, oneString)

    i += 1

print(replacedStrings)
```

**My aim here is:** I need the values only (without the escaped sequences) as the split strings.

**My approach here is:**

1. I have split the string by `\n` that gives me array list of separate strings.
2. Then, I have checked each string using the regex, if the regex matches, then the matched substring is replaced to "".
3. Then I have pushed those strings to a collection, thinking that it will store the replaced strings in the new array list.

So basically, I am through with 1 and 2, but currently I am stuck at 3. Following is my Output:

```
1
2
3

4

['1\r\r\t\r', '2\r\r', '3\r\r\r\r', '\r', '\r4', '\r']
```

Comment: While I don't understand everything what your regexp is trying to achieve, I see one major flaw: You are trying to match verbatim `\` while `String` does not contain any. The `\` in `String` are only for escaping, they are not there!

Comment: oops. Comment formatting problem. ...`\\` while `String`... The `\\` in `String`... Doesn't work either? How to put backslash in code quote? ...backslash while String...The backslash in String...

Comment: @mkiever No idea, I tried both the ways, seems like an issue that SO might want to work on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there, I would just use `string.strip()` to replace multiple `\r` and `\n` at the start and the end of the strings

```
String = "1\r\r\t\r\n2\r\r\n3\r\r\r\r\n\r\n\r4\n\r"
splitString = String.split('\n')
replacedStrings = []
i=0

for oneString in splitString:
    s = oneString.strip()
    if s != '':
        print(s)
        replacedStrings.append(s)

print(replacedStrings)
```

The output will look like

```
1
2
3
4
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

For `"jkahdjkah \r\r\t\r\nA: B\r\r\nA : B\r\r\r\r\n\r\n\r4\n\r"`, the output will be `['jkahdjkah', 'A: B', 'A : B', '4']`

Comment: I have a question here, your code works perfectly, but why doesn't `re.sub` work?

Comment: Perhaps because the substitution string is incorrect!

Comment: IMO, the replace is unnecessary. `strip` does everything you need.

Comment: Then,what substitution string can I use to make that code work?

Comment: Also for your other string, the output given by my code is `['jkahdjkah', 'A: B', 'A : B', '4']`, is that what is expected?

Comment: @mkiever, that's cool, I mean `strip()` sure is useful, but I am curious, what is wrong with my substitution string?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh yes, this is what I need out of the code.

Comment: Great, I would say if things can be done with `strip`, why complicate things with regex, besides Tim's answer above gives a great explanation of why `re.sub` is bad here!

Comment: Also, if my answer helped you @Code_Ninja , please accept and upvote it :)

Comment: This one is really cool, thanks, although Tim's answer is more optimised than this. This answer helped me find the issue with my approach.

Comment: Yes, I always like to start with the basics and then build onto regex

Comment: @Code_Ninja: Just to explain why your `sub` didn't work like you expected. You used start `^` and end `$` anchor in your regex while doing `sub` which would match the whole string if at all it matched and whole string then would have been replaced with empty string which isn't what you desired. Instead you should have used `oneString = re.sub(r'[\r\t]+', "", oneString)` to correctly replace all `\r` and `\t` from your string and would have given you the right output.

Comment: In fact, what you were trying to do could have been done in a one liner code an didn't had to do the initial split using `\n` and then use the for loops and multiple subs. Instead with the right usage of `strip()` and `sub` you could have easily got the intended split. [Check this code demo](https://rextester.com/YNHNT23933)

Comment: If I am trying to remove the spaces from the `['jkahdjkah', 'A: B', 'A : B', '4']`, what should I do? I mean this should be converted to `['jkahdjkah', 'A:B', 'A:B', '4']`, there is no space between `A` and `B`. What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You might find it easier to use `re.findall` here with the simple pattern `\S+`:

```
input = "1\r\r\t\r\n2\r\r\n3\r\r\r\r\n\r\n\r4\n\r"
output = re.findall(r'\S+', input)
print(output)

['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

This approach will isolate and match any islands of one or more non whitespace characters.

**Edit:**

Based on your new input data, we can try matching on the pattern `[^\r\n\t]+`:

```
input = "jkahdjkah \r\r\t\r\nA: B\r\r\nA : B\r\r\r\r\n\r\n\r4\n\r"
output = re.findall(r'[^\r\n\t]+', input)
print(output)

['jkahdjkah ', 'A: B', 'A : B', '4']
```

`re.sub` isn't really the right tool for the job here.  What would be on the table is `split` or `re.findall`, because you want to repeatedly match/isolate a certain part of your text.  `re.sub` is useful for taking a string and transforming it to something else.  It *can* be used to extract text, but does not work so well for multiple matches.

Comment: This fails for the this input `"jkahdjkah  \r\r\t\r\nA:  B\r\r\nA  : B\r\r\r\r\n\r\n\r4\n\r"`, where the output should give me `['jkahdjkah', 'A:  B', 'A  : B', 4]`, whereas, the output is `['jkahdjkah', 'A:', 'B', 'A', ':', 'B', '4']`

Comment: @Code_Ninja Then match on `[^\r\n\t]+`, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: this is really cool, but my doubt still exists, what's wrong with `re.sub()`, why doesn't that work, can you please add some explanation in your answer regarding that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found one more method, this seems to work fine, it might not be as optimised as the other answers, but its just another way:

```
import re
splitString = []
String = "jhgdf\r\r\t\r\nA  : B\r\r\nA  : B\r\r\r\r\n\r\n\rA: B\n\r"
splitString = re.compile('[\r\t\n]+').split(String)
if "" in splitString:
  splitString.remove("")
print(splitString)
```

I added it here, so that people going through the same trouble as me, might want to overlook this approach too.

Following is the Output that I have got after using the above code:

```
['jhgdf', 'A  : B', 'A  : B', 'A: B']
```